# Не плавная анимация при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, scrollmagic

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, при скролле картинка перемещается не плавно. Использовал для анимации GSAP & ScrollMagic. Как можно сделать эту анимацию более плавной?

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/daunppictures/pen/KKdXQPY

```
<body>
    <div class="outher-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container animation">
                <header class="header">
                    <img src="img/sword.jpg" alt="" class="logo">
                </header>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="main-text">
                        <div class="main-text__header">
                            Hello
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-text__body">
                            I'm HTML coder
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/samur.png" alt="" class="samur-img">
                    <img src="img/red_circle.png" alt="" class="red-circle">
                    <img src="img/reeds.png" alt="" class="reeds">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container two">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 200vw;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    max-width: 100px;
}
.samur-img {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 80vw;
    max-width: 300px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.red-circle {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 70vw;
    bottom: -150px;
}
.main-text {
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    margin: 2rem 0 0 7rem;
    padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
.main-text__header {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 90px;
}
.main-text__body {
    font-size: 60px;
}
.reeds {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -140px;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.outher-wrapper {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.animation {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
const flightPath = {
    curviness: 1,
    autoRotate: false,
    values: [
        {x: 0, y: 700}
    ]
}

const tween = new TimelineLite();

tween.add(
    TweenLite.to('.samur-img', 8, {
        bezier: flightPath,
        ease: Power0.easeOut
    })
);

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: .015,
        reverse: true
    },
    vertical: false
});

const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '.animation',
    duration: 2600,
})
.setTween(tween)
.addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 3):

Анимацию можно сделать более плавной если добавить CSS свойство transition для изображения которые анимируются

```
.samur-img {
   transition: .3s;
}
```

Comment: Какой стыд, я даже не подумал об этом... Благодарю.